# Fading out all the divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have built a function that will display a notification each time an ajax request is send and I just call the `showAjaxAlert()` function :

```
function showAjaxAlert(message, type) {
    var rand = randomNumber(100000, 1000000);
    document.getElementById('notification_area').innerHTML = document.getElementById('notification_area').innerHTML + '<div class="ajax-notification ajax-notification-' + type + ' ajax-notification-' + rand + ' alert">' + message + '</div>';
    $('.ajax-notification-' + rand).delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

I use a random number for each div to keep track of what im fading out, here is the random number function:

```
function randomNumber(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

I store all my ajax notifications in 1 parent div with the id of "notification_area"

```
<div id="notification_area"></div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#notification_area {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2em;
    opacity: 0.8;
    right: 2em;
}

.ajax-notification{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
}
```

But the issue is, if the first one hasn't faded before another alert shows, it stays there forever and only the most recent alert fades out and its like I have to wait for the previous alert to fade out before I can send another ajax alert. Why is this happening, and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Do you want to fadeout all the notifications before shows the new one??

Comment: I just don't want the previous notificiations to get stuck and not fade out if I launch another notification before the previous ones faded out. Right now if I launch a notification (second one) before the first one fades out the second one will fade out and the first one will just be stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you could use `append()` instead of `innerHTML` so it will just add the new notification without touching the old ones so the delay will work fine, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
function showAjaxAlert(message, type) {
  var rand = randomNumber(100000, 1000000);

  $('#notification_area').append('<div class="ajax-notification ajax-notification-' + type + ' ajax-notification-' + rand + ' alert">' + message + '</div>');

  $('.ajax-notification-' + rand).delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
}

function randomNumber(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

$('#show').on('click', function(){
  showAjaxAlert('Test Message','Success');
})
```

```css
#notification_area {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2em;
  opacity: 0.8;
  right: 2em;
}

.ajax-notification{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="notification_area"></div>
<button id="show">Show notification</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need the randon number and a randon name here.

```
function showAjaxAlert(message, type) {
  var notificationArea = $('#notification_area'); 
  var notification = $("<div>")
            .addClass("ajax-notification")
            .addClass("ajax-notification-" + type)
            .addClass("alert")
            .html(message);
  notification.appendTo(notificationArea);

  notification.delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

The trick is that 'notification' is a native object for this function so it will fade it out after a second.

Comment: You can add multiple classes within the same .addClass() call like... `.addClass('ajax-notification ajax-notification-type alert')`. Using multiple calls keeps the code pretty clean but you sacrifice performance on a grander scale.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.append() and I suggest you reference the newly added alert with an id instead of a class for performance reasons.

Check out this fiddle which appears to be doing what you want...

https://jsfiddle.net/s2zxh5uh/

```
function showAjaxAlert(message, type) 
{
    var rand = randomNumber(100000, 1000000);
    $('#notification_area').append('<div id="ajax-notification-'+rand+'" class="ajax-notification ajax-notification-' + type + ' alert">' + message + '</div>');
    $('#ajax-notification-' + rand).delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
}  

function randomNumber(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```